# Possible bug in data.table binary search?

Tags: r, data.table

I am having issues with the data.table package in R.

Consider a simple data set:

```
require(data.table)
dat <- read.table(text="       x  y
[1,]  -1 99
[2,]   5  4
[3,]  10 -2
[4,] 600  0
[5,] -16  1
[6,]   0 55", header=TRUE)
```

Now suppose I want to use data.table on this dataset (mainly because I want to do binary search)

```
DT = data.table(dat, key="x")
setkey(DT, x) #not sure if this is necessary
```

It works fine if the key I'm looking for is actually in the dataset:

```
DT[J(-16)]
     x y
1: -16 1
```

But if I ask for a key that is NOT part of the data:

```
> DT[J(-22)]
     x  y
1: -22 NA
```

When I'm looking for the same result as here:

```
> DT[x==-22]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: x,y
```

This is a simple example, but it returns an actual dataset of length 1, which is very tedious if I want to work with that result further (in a loop, which may occasionally create empty subsets)

Furthermore, if there are many columns it seems to fill some of them with pretty much random data, along with NA's, this is what I see in my actual data:

I have a dataset with bunch of variables, key is studyid. I ask for a subset by studyid that is not part of the data:

```
DTpharm[J(154759)]
   studyid RXSUP RXAMT RXMD                 NDC              GPI_CD class date
1:  154759    NA    NA   NA 9218868437227407266 9218868437227407266    NA <NA>
```

Where the NDC and GPI variables are integer64. (notice how the values are the same?!)

Am I missing something/ do you know of a way to do binary search that returns an empty set if I ask for a key that is not there?

Comment: No, that is by design. Use `nomatch=0` as documented at `help("[.data.table")` if you want no results returned. Joins with `J` are different from subsetting. Not sure about that weird thing happening with integer64, though.

Comment: Oh, that solves it, thanks! When I add ,nomatch=0 it works as desired in all cases. Thank you

Comment: And try require(bit64) then the two integer64 columns should display NA.  `fread` will have issued a warning asking you to require(bit64).  Maybe we need to add a warning in the print method too.

Comment: Yep, updated [FR#975](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/975) to add warning to print method.

Comment: Although the original post does not mention it, I do actually have bit64 loaded and it still prints the two columns wrong.